# Como iniciar um áudio automaticamente na inicialização de uma aplicação Java?

Tags: java, áudio

estou com dificuldade para iniciar essa aplicação juntamente com um áudio "mixx.mp3". Não tenho erros, mas o som não reproduz.

```
public class MostrarLuta {

    URL som = MostrarLuta.class.getResource("mixx.mp3");
    AudioClip Som = Applet.newAudioClip(som);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaInicial telaInicial = new TelaInicial();
        telaInicial.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //telaInicial.setSize(1366, 768); // tamanho da tela
        telaInicial.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centraliza o JFrame
        telaInicial.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        telaInicial.setVisible(true);

        MostrarLuta music = new MostrarLuta();
        System.out.println(music.som);
        System.out.println("\n"+music.Som);
        music.Som.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Já instalou o plugin de mp3 no java? [https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html)

Comment: já instalei, mas não funcionou. A solução que eu encontrei foi converter o áudio de mp3 para wav

dessa forma deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, eu estava fazendo um aplicativo desktop java que precisava executar som em mp3, wav, etc. No inicio eu tentei utilizar essa classe que você está usando, o AudioClip, porém sem sucesso. O problema pelo que parece não é código mas sim o fato de não ser um applet (acredito que seja o mesmo com esse seu projeto. Você está criando um applet?). Estão mudei o projeto para usar JLayer (http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) . JLayer é uma biblioteca para executar arquivos de áudio. Esse funcionou legal.